# Pin::as_mut(&mut self)

Tags: rust

From the source for [`Pin::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.as_mut) - **pin.rs:**

```
impl<P: DerefMut> Pin<P> {
    ...
    pub fn as_mut(&mut self) -> Pin<&mut P::Target> {    
        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut *self.pointer) }
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't understand why `&mut *self.pointer` is used instead of `self.pointer`, What is wrong with the following sentence?

```
unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(self.pointer) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Pin::new_unchecked(self.pointer)` would just return a `Pin<P>` instead of a `Pin<&mut P::Target>`, deref coercions won't be considered. It will also attempt to *move* `pointer` out of `self` and cause a compiler error.

Using `*` will *dereference* `self.pointer` into a `P::Target` and `&mut` makes it return a mutable reference.